# PHP function not returning values for dynamic drop down

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing issue in my dynamic drop down function it not return values i am unable to find where i'm doing wrong.One more issue i am facing regarding this code is that it not open drop down according to menus i.e if i select USA as a country it not show related cities of USA it always show all cities of all countries please set my code i will be highly thankful to you.

```
function listcatagoery()
{
  $query="select * from tblcountry";
  $rs=mysqli_query($query);  

  $html ='<select name="listcatagoery" id="listcatagoery" onchange="submitme();">';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
  {
     if($cntid == $row['cnt_id'])
    {
    $html.='<option selected="selected"  
    value="'.$row['cnt_id'].'">'.$row['cnt_name'].'</option>';  
      }
      else
      {
          $html.='<option   
           value="'.$row['cnt_id'].'">'.$row['cnt_name'].'</option>';   
          }
  }
      $html.='</select>';
      return $html;
    }


///////////////////// List sub-catagoery////////

function listsubcatagoery()
{
  $query = "select * from tblcity";
  $rs=mysqli_query($query);
  $html='<select name="listsubcatagoery" id="listsubcatagoery">';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
  {
    $html.='<option value="'.$row['cit_id'].'">
    '.$row['cit_name'].'</option>';  
      } 
      $html.='</select>';
      return $html;
    }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="right">
    <h2>User Registration Here...</h2><br />

    <form name="frmadd" id="frmadd" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="4" width="90%" align="center">


        <tr>
          <td>Full Name</td>
          <td><input type=text name="textname" size="40" id="textname" required="required"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Gender</td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="rdgender" value="male" size="10">Male
            <input type="radio" name="rdgender" value="Female" size="10">Female</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td><input type=text name="textemail" size="40" id="textemail" required="required"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="textpass" size="40" id="textpass" required="required"><span class="first"></span></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
          <td>Country</td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $htmlcountry; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>City</td>
          <td>
            <?php echo $htmlcity; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Telephone</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="txttel" size="11" id="txttel" required="required"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Photo</td>
          <td><input type="file" name="txtphoto" size="40" id="txtphoto"></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td>Signin</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btnadd" id="btnadd" value="SigIn Now" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </form><br />
  </div>
```

Comment: `if($cntid == $row['cnt_id'])` where is `$cntid` set in your first function? `"select * from tblcity"` You select all cities, why would you expect to return it something different? Use a `where` clause to limit to a specific country

Comment: Your first problem is likely `"select * from tblcity"` because you are selecting all the cities, and it does not matter which country they are in. Actually I as far as I see `tblcountry` and `tblcity` are independant. You should recheck your SQL statements and table design, also it is a good idea to add missing info.

Comment: You also don't seem to be using any of your two functions from above, `echo $htmlcountry;` where is `$htmlcountry;` set?